# Howto read "old" sqlite in flutter?

Tags: android, sqlite, flutter

I rewrote my existing android app using flutter.

Is it possible to access the old database that my old app created? If i make a SELECT on the old table, i don't get any data.

Old app:

```java
private final static String DB_NAME = "oweapp";
```

new app:

```dart
String path = join(documentsDirectory.path, "oweapp.db");
```

Comment: there is a minor bug in your code. fixing this minor bug will get your desired output.

Comment: if you mean ".db", I tried it with and without the file extension.

Answer (score 0):

If you provide the database in the assets folder you should copy the database to de device first. If not, opening a database in the external storage of the device (as you are doing) should work.

```
ByteData data = await rootBundle.load("assets/oweapp.db");
List<int> bytes = data.buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes);

final directory = await getDatabasesPath();
String dbPath = join(directory, "oweapp.db");
await File(dbPath).writeAsBytes(bytes);

// After that you can do:
var db = await openDatabase(dbPath);
```

Comment: What is the output of File(dbPath).exists() ? And how are you accessing the data?